# How can i get Cookie value in TWIG?

Tags: php, twig

I have login form and I want to change it on logout button.
Here is code:

```
<nav class="flex">
        {% if app.request.cookies.get('user') == NULL %}
        {% embed "Backend/loginForm.php" %}

        {% endembed  %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if app.request.cookies.get('user') != NULL %}
            {{"logged"}}
        {% endif %}
    <div class="btn searchBtn" id="searchBtn">
        SEARCH
    </div>
</nav>
```

Cookie['user'] is set but  app.request.cookies.get('user') always return me FALSE. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you using symfony/silex?

Comment: I don't use any framework here. Need I use symfony to do that or is any way to do it without?

Comment: `app.request` is something from symfony yes. You could mock it though if you don't to use the framework

Comment: Twig is just a template system, it has no idea about cookies or anything. You need to inject that as data when you render the template.

Comment: Is it a good idea to set TWIG global variables and use them in if? Or better way is use symfony? I want to point out that i don't know how to work with frameworks yet.

Comment: You can create a custom class `Request` and add your cookie/session/... in there and pass that along

Comment: What are you working on? A theme or a module?